# Haskell/GHC: overlapping instances reported while context only allows a single one

Tags: haskell, ghc, overlapping-instances

Dear Haskell/GHC experts,

I don't really understand why GHC reports overlapping instances while only one is actually valid according the provided contexts. For instance, let's consider the following piece of code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

class C a where
    foo :: a -> String
    foo x = "OK"

instance C Bool
instance (C a) => C [a]
instance (C a) => C [(Char, a)]

main = print $ foo [('a', True)]
```

Compiling it gives:

```
Test.hs:13:16: error:
    * Overlapping instances for C [(Char, Bool)]
        arising from a use of `foo'
      Matching instances:
        instance C a => C [a] -- Defined at Test.hs:9:10
        instance C a => C [(Char, a)] -- Defined at Test.hs:11:10
    * In the second argument of `($)', namely `foo [('a', True)]'
      In the expression: print $ foo [('a', True)]
      In an equation for `main': main = print $ foo [('a', True)]
```

The point is that `('a', True)` has type `(Char, Bool)` which is not an instance of `C`. Therefore, `instance C a => C [a]` is not applicable to the value `[('a', True)]`.

Therefore, why does GHC consider it?

The question is really about understanding the behaviour of GHC, not about how to avoid the issue (e.g. using `OverlappingInstances`). Is it because contexts are not used when "resolving" a function call? And if so, why?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding (could be very wrong):

First, from the [documentation](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.0.1/docs/html/users_guide/type-class-extensions.html#instance-overlap):

> When matching, GHC takes no account of the context of the instance
>   declaration (context1 etc). GHC's default behaviour is that exactly
>   one instance must match the constraint it is trying to resolve. It is fine for there to be a potential of overlap (by including both declarations (A) and (B), say); an error is only reported if a particular constraint matches more than one.
>
> The -XOverlappingInstances flag instructs GHC to allow more than one
>   instance to match, provided there is a most specific one.

In your case, the type passed to `foo` is `[(Char,Bool)]`. This satisfies the generic `[a]` and the more specialised `[(Char,a)]`. In the absence of `OverlappingInstances` flag, the most specific match scenario does not apply, and an error is reported.

Now if you were to tweak your code slightly like so:

```
instance C Bool
instance (C a) => C [a]
instance (C a) => C (Char, a)
```

Then there would be no overlap, because a tuple is not a list.

Comment: Thanks a lot Shree. So basically, it looks like it is simply "the way GHC works" on this (non-standard) extension. I close the question.